# Assign raster's pixel values to a new column

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, classification, training

I want to use a landcover raster for further training in GEE. This raster has different pixel values for different landcover classes. However, I want to assign those values in a new column to use this column as a property for my training data, How can I do this?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/188a116b282875bfd7fa160f66a25ac1

```js
//EG--Define a set of classification values and corresponding class names.
var classes = {
  5: 'Bare',
  7: 'Artificial',
  10: 'Potato',
  12: 'Fallow',
  13: 'Orchard (dense) ',
  15: 'Grapes ',
  19: 'Water ',
  108: 'Irrigated wheat',
  109: ' Irrigated maize',
  110: ' Irrigated potatoes',
  113: ' Irrigated orchard (dense)',
  115: ' Irrigated grapes',
  120: ' Irrigated rice ',
  124: 'Irrigated cotton',
  125: 'Irrigated clover ',
  126: 'Irrigated onions',
  127: 'Irrigated carrots',
  128: 'Irrigated eggplants',
  129: 'Irrigated flax',
  131: 'Irrigated sugar beet',
  22: 'Sugarcane',
  122: 'Sugarcane',
  121: 'Irrigated mixed crops',
  225: 'no data',
};
// Use the classify function to apply the class values to the image.
///Egypt///

var labeled = lc_EG.remap([5,7,10,12,13,15,19,108,109,110,113,115,120,124,125,126,127,128,129,131,225],
[5,7,10,12,13,15,19,108,109,110,113,115,120,124,125,126,127,128,129,131,225])
.set('description', classes);
///convert it to Geometery to be able to use in sample region////
// var class_value=lc_EG.get('Value').getInfo();
// print(class_value);
var geometry_EG = labeled.geometry();
print(geometry_EG);

// Add the labeled image to the map
Map.addLayer(labeled, {min: 5, max: 131, palette: []}, 'labeled',false);
var class_value=lc_EG.get('Value').getInfo();
print(classes)

///Ethopia///

var labeled_Eth = LC_Ethop.remap([22,122,121],
[22,122,121])
.set('description', classes);


// Add the labeled image to the map
//Map.addLayer(labeled_Eth, {min: 22, max: 122, palette: []}, 'labeled_Eth');
Map.addLayer(labeled_Eth, {}, 'labeled_Eth',false);
var class_value=LC_Ethop.get('classes').getInfo();
//print(classes)
///convert it to Geometery to be able to use in sample region////
var geometry_ETH = labeled_Eth.geometry();
print(geometry_ETH);

                  ///////Landsat data/////
// Define a function that scales and masks Landsat 8 surface reflectance images.
function prepSrL8(image) {
  // Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var getFactorImg = function(factorNames) {
    var factorList = image.toDictionary().select(factorNames).values();
    return ee.Image.constant(factorList);
  };
  var scaleImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var offsetImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var scaled = image.select('SR_B.|ST_B10').multiply(scaleImg).add(offsetImg);

  // Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
  return image.addBands(scaled, null, true)
    .updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask);
}


// Make a cloud-free Landsat 8 surface reflectance composite.
var dates = [
// ee.DateRange('2020-04-01', '2020-04-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-04-16', '2020-05-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-01', '2020-05-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-16', '2020-06-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-01', '2020-06-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-16', '2020-07-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-01', '2020-07-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-16', '2020-08-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-01', '2020-08-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-16', '2020-09-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-01', '2020-09-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-16', '2020-10-01'),
//ee.DateRange('2020-10-01', '2020-10-16'),
  
]
//var bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5',
            // 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']
             
var addNDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDWI = function(img) {
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
}

// //EVI
var addEVI= function(image){
  var evi= image.expression(
              '2.5*(NIR-RED)/(NIR+6*RED-7.5*BLUE+10000)',{
              NIR:image.select('SR_B5'),
              RED:image.select('SR_B4'),
              BLUE:image.select('SR_B2'),
            }).float().rename('EVI')
  return image.addBands(evi)
}

var list = dates.map(function(range) {
  return ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterDate(ee.DateRange(range))
      .filter(ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.bounds(ROI),
    ee.Filter.bounds(ROI_Eth)
  ))
  //.filterBounds(ROI)
      .map(addNDVI)
      .map(addNDWI)
      .map(addEVI)
      .select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI','NDWI'])
      //.select(['NDVI','NDWI','EVI'])
      //.mean()
      .median()
      .rename(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5','SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI','NDWI'])
      //.rename(['NDVI','NDWI','EVI'])
});

var clipped = ROI.merge(ROI_Eth);
/////create a stacked layer///
var stacked = ee.ImageCollection(list).toBands().clip(clipped);
Map.addLayer(stacked, {bands: ["3_NDVI", "5_NDVI", "8_NDVI"]}, 'Stacked', false)

print(stacked,'stacked')



// //Generate 50000 random pt sample
var random1 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: geometry_EG,
  points: 3000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})
var random2 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: geometry_ETH,
  points: 2000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})



// // Place the collections in a new collection.

var combined = ee.FeatureCollection([random1,random2]);

// // Flatten the collection to create a new collection with all the features.
var flattened = combined.flatten();

var label='classes'

// // // // Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var sample = stacked.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  'collection': flattened,
  'properties':[label],
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  'scale': 30,
  //crs: 'EPSG:32636',
  'tileScale': 2
});


// // Filter out the null property values and split data////
var trainingNoNulls = sample.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(stacked.bandNames().add("classes"))
  )
var sample=trainingNoNulls.randomColumn();
var split=0.7
var training_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split));
var validation_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));

          ////// Train the classifier////
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100)
  .train({
    features: training_sample,
    //.randomColumn().filter("random < 0.7"),
    classProperty: 'classes',
    inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),
    
  })


var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified')


// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that similar to what you have already done (using `sampleRegions`). One easy way to do that is simply stack the class band as another image to your band stack and then use `sampleRegion`. This way the class property will be included in your Features. Just add the following lines before creating the `sample` object. Since `labeled` and `labeled_Eth` are images from different locations, I first made a composite of both using a reducer, and renamed this image as 'classes'.

```
var labelsIm = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([labeled,labeled_Eth])
                           .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
                           .rename('classes');
stacked = stacked.addBands(labelsIm)
```